# Parsing a XML File in Jquery

Tags: xml-parsing

I had an html file "search.html" and an xml file "videos.xml" located in same directory, I used the following code to parse it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "videos.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("Video").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).find("id").text();
        alert(id);    
    }
}
```

This code works in the server(when i run as a web application) 
 i.e localhost:8080/mysite/search.html

but it is not working locally without server.
 i.e file:///D:/mysite/search.html

I think it could not get the path of xml file, i tried by giving both relative path and absolute path but it does not work. So please help me to solve this.

thank you,

P.Naresh